# Vuetify v-select menu covers text-field input

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I don’t want the menu to cover the input box.  My Vuetify version is 2.3.18.  How do I fix this?

I found this but it doesn't work for me:
https://codepen.io/jrast/pen/NwMaZE?editors=1010

I found a Vuetify github bug:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2377

Vuetify `v-select` Codepen example:
https://codepen.io/zmrqodfu/pen/abZeVOP?editors=101

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
  },
  data () {
    return {
      select: { state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL' },
      hideDetails: false,
      items: [
        { state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL' },
        { state: 'Georgia', abbr: 'GA' },
        { state: 'Nebraska', abbr: 'NE' },
        { state: 'California', abbr: 'CA' },
        { state: 'New York', abbr: 'NY' }
      ]
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.3/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<div id="app">
    <v-app dark>
       <v-select
            v-bind:items="items"
            v-model="select"
            label="Select"
            single-line
            :hide-details="hideDetails"
            hint="Hint of Select"
            item-text="state"
            item-value="abbr"
            return-object
            autocomplete
          ></v-select>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `menu-props` prop:

```js
:menu-props="{ bottom: true, offsetY: true }"
```

Or, here's how you could position the menu manually:

**CSS**

```css
.v-menu__content {
   margin-top: 65px;
}
```

Your updated [Codepen](https://codepen.io/sh0ber/pen/dyXxZZo)